# question about common bit sequences

Tags: algorithm

suppose we have two numbers i want write  program which print common bits subsequent which occurs in  these number
or

```
 1000010111001010100011110001010010101001011101001001001
0101 01110011011001010111101111111010001001011
```

one of the answer should be `0101`
but constraint is that we should make bitwise operations and mathematical operations
  and not string  problems ( longest  common subsequent)
 thanks

Comment: Dont really understand your question...

Comment: how and where from did u get 0101? elaborate more on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
common_ones = a & b;
common_zeros = ~a & ~b;
common_sequences = common_ones | common_zeros;
```

for example:

```
a 1000010111001010100011110001010010101001011101001001001
b 0000000000010101110011011001010111101111111010001001011
c 0111101000100000101111010111111010111001011000111111101
```

to clear the single bit sequences you can use this:

```
c = c & ( c >> 1 );
c = c | ( c << 1 );

c 0111100000000000001111000111111000111000011000111111100
```

It is not clear if this is what you want, but this is a quick and easy way to find all common bit sequences at the same position in two values.  If you are looking for common bit sequences at any position, you would need to rotate one value into each bit position and perform the above tests.

Comment: alternatively common_seqence = ~(a^b)

Comment: I think @user want to ask to find the binary longest common sub-sequence using bitwise operations. Your solution mostly does the work but it needs to find longest 1's sequence in 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two 32 bit ints a and b. Shift the bits in b by i, and wrap them around (so that the bit that falls out on the right will come in on the left) and xor it with a. Let i go from 0 to 31. This will give you 32 results. If my reasoning is correct, the result with the longest common subsequence should be the one with the most 0s (counting the 0s can be done in a loop for instance). If not, this should at least be a good starting point.

Comment: please how me a few example i did not understand well

Comment: @davit-datuashvili, instead of continuing to ask for spoon-feed answers, I suggest you react to the comments to your question for once. But I get the impression you are immune to them: I have never seen you answer any request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Sequitur](http://sequitur.info)-Algorithm.